The image of a bounded set is a bounded set
Let $\alpha: (0,1)\to \mathbb R^2$ is a continious map that maps the subset $X\subset (0,1)$ to $\alpha(X)$.
Prove or disprove: If $X$ is a bounded subset of $(0,1)$ then its image $\alpha(X)$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^2$.
I know that for continuous maps, the image of a compact set is compact, and compact subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ are bounded. However, since $X$ is only given as bounded (not necessarily compact), I’m unsure whether this implies that $α(X)$ will always be bounded.
Can someone help me clarify whether the boundedness of $X$ ensures that $α(X)$ is also bounded, or provide a counterexample if this is not the case?

What would be an unbounded subset of $(0,1)$?

Can you solve it in the case $\alpha: ]0,1[\to \Bbb R$?

More or less twice the same question at the same time:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5001186/349785.

You are right. If $X$ were compact, then the result would hold. However now we can always take $X=(0,1)$ as that is a bounded subset of $(0,1)$. Also take for example $\alpha(x)=\left(\frac1x,0\right)$. Then $\alpha((0,1))=(1,\infty)\times\{0\}$ which is unbounded.

Wow you have been slightly faster.

Take $\alpha(x)=(1/x,0)$, then $\alpha((0,1))=(1,\infty)\times\{0\}$ is unbounded.
